# Scala shapeless zip issue

Tags: scala, shapeless

In the example below, I get *could not find implicit value for parameter zipper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Zip[shapeless.::[keys.Out,shapeless.::[mapper.Out,shapeless.HNil]]]*

I presume I need another implicit, but can't work out the syntax. Ideas?

```
def mapCCLV[P <: Product, K <: HList, L <: HList, M <: HList](p: P)(poly: Poly1)(
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L], lab: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, K], 
    keys: Keys[K], mapper: Mapper.Aux[poly.type, L, M]) = {
  val k = keys.apply
  val v = gen.to(p).map(poly)
  k.zip(v)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error message says, you need an extra implicit parameter for a `Zip` type class instance, to be able to zip.

```
import shapeless._, shapeless.ops.hlist._, record._, ops.record._, labelled._

def mapCCLV[P <: Product, LG <: HList, K <: HList, G <: HList, M <: HList](
  p: P)(poly: Poly1
)(implicit 
  gen: Generic.Aux[P, G],
  lab: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, LG], 
  keys: Keys.Aux[LG, K], 
  mapper: Mapper.Aux[poly.type, G, M],
  zip: Zip[K :: M :: HNil]
): zip.Out = {
  val k = keys()
  val v = gen.to(p).map(poly)
  k.zip(v)
}
```

More likely you want to use `ZipWithKeys` instead of `Zip`.

```
def mapCCLV[P <: Product, LG <: HList, K <: HList, G <: HList, M <: HList, Out <: HList](
  p: P)(poly: Poly1
)(implicit 
  gen: Generic.Aux[P, G],
  lab: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, LG], 
  keys: Keys.Aux[LG, K], 
  mapper: Mapper.Aux[poly.type, G, M],
  zwk: ZipWithKeys.Aux[K, M, Out]
) = gen.to(p).map(poly).zipWithKeys(keys())
```

Comment: The first example works. However I think something isn't quite right with the second - it simply returns the mapped HList without the keys. I've tried several permutations of keys/zwk etc with little luck.

Comment: You get a record with the same keys as `LG`. You can see `with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag ...` in the type of the result.